# Why does Bq M10 tablet file manager make duplicates when renaming?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, filemanager, aquaris, bq, m10

Using the Bq M10 tablet file manager to rename files  located on the microSD card, a duplicate un-renamed file is copied onto the device itself, creating a duplicate and cluttering.

Why?